# PHP: Including files for template

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, view

I am trying to build my own simple template handler to easily be able to nest and combine files into variables and call these variables when neccessary, as shown below:

```
$partial['header'] = 'header.php';

foreach($partial as $part => $view ) {
    $output[$name] = file_get_contents( APPPATH .'views/' . $view . '.php' );
}

extract($output, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'template' );

include 'mytemplate.php';
```

The `mytemplate.php` template file:

```
<?php
echo $template_header; // Shows the header.
```

**The question:**
Obviously, loading a PHP file by `file_get_contents` isn't going to call any PHP code inside the loaded file and I am sure that there's better options available then using `eval`. **What should I change to be able to use PHP inside my template files?**

Comment: FYI - a believe the code above will result in a path of `header.php.php`, since `$view` will be `header.php` and `.php` is appended in `file_get_contents`.

Comment: Hi Hamish, yep - that's correct. I oversaw that when copying the code onto SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More ugly is possible but doing exactly what you're wanting :

```
function custom_get_content($filename){
    if (is_file($filename)) {
        ob_start();
        include $filename;
        $contents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $contents;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it :

```
foreach($partial as $part => $view ) {
    $output[$name] = custom_get_content( APPPATH .'views/' . $view . '.php' );
}
```

I copied that from a comment in the PHP manual but can't find it anymore (and that's why maybe it's too ugly :D)

Comment: Wow, accepted while editing... @Industrial : Tell me if the edit cancel your decision ;)

Comment: Nope that's exactly what I wanted! :) Thanks a lot Shikiryu!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the scripts in is obiously not the best approach. You'll have to `eval` them.

And just for the record:

```
 include($filename);
```

Is functionally identical to:

```
 eval("?>" . file_get_contents($filename));
```

Get over it. The "eval is evil" meme is just that, a meme. So if you want to keep your appraoch, you could just use `eval("?>$template_header");` instead of `echo`.

The alternative would be to skip the file reading, and have your `$template_vars` contain filenames rather than their content. Then do an ordinary `include($template_header);`